# Service "app.locale_listener" must implement interface

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use sticky locale changes on a symfony2 app. 
Using [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html) guide from the official documentation.

But I am getting an error:

```
Service "app.locale_listener" must implement interface "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface".
```

The thing is that this class already implements the `EventSubscriberInterface`.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
```

I am using *Symfony 2.8*.

Anyone came across this error?

Comment: let's see your class

Comment: @Federico is the same class on the documentation. I copy pasted it.

Comment: you keep the same namespace? in which folder did you put the class?

Comment: Let's see your class; there is an error. @Federico It's not an autoloading problem

Comment: I have the same error, how did you fix it?

Comment: Found, it was because the filename didn't match the class name (LanguageListener.php instead of LocaleListener)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a

```
tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

in your service configure `service.yaml`. take it out, the error gone.